# Python list and c/c++ arrays

Tags: c++, python, c, list

For e.g. if we have an array in python `arr = [1,3,4]`. We can delete element in the array by just using `arr.remove(element)` ot `arr.pop()` and list will mutate and it's length will change and that element won't be there. Is there a way to do this is C ot C++?. If yes the how to do that?

Comment: Do you mean a `[]` array, or a STL `array<>`?

Comment: i mean just the standart list in python like so a = ['spam', 'eggs', 100, 1234]. I don't have a clue what's a STL array<> is.

Comment: ... C/C++ doesn't have a "standard list", and it certainly doesn't have Python's.

Comment: I just need to know how to do what I asked) can you help with that?

Comment: Not unless you can answer a very simple question.

Comment: The problem is, the answer really depends on whether you mean C or C++- C/C++ isn't a language. C provides bare-bones arrays which are not classes and provide no user-friendly member functions such as `pop()`. C++ provides a few array-like classes that do provide many useful methods.

Comment: A potentially useful link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914233/what-is-the-underlying-data-structure-for-python-lists).

Answer (score 5):

I guess you're looking for `std::vector` (or other containers in the standard library).

Comment: but how I implement such a method without the standart library? is there a way to do this in C?

Comment: @IgorZimenko You asked "C or C++" (and tagged just `C++`), so I answered for C++. In C, you'll have to implement this yourself. If you want to do that, just try it and if you hit concrete problems, ask new question(s) here on SO (tagged `C`). If you don't know where to start, reading a book on data structures might be in order.

Comment: @Angew: std::deque would be the closest approximation

Comment: @IgorZimenko How to implement without the standard library? You pretty much have to reimplement most of what `std::vector` does.  (It's not really as difficult as it sounds, if you ignore the allocator business.)

Comment: @Abhijit I don't see where `std::deque` would be any more appropriate than `std::vector`.  Python lists provide both random access (`[]`) and removal/insertion at arbitrary places.  Not to mention things like `l[3::3] = 3 * [ 0 ]`, to set every third element to 0.

Comment: @Abhijit after some reading, I have concluded that the closest C++ equivalent is `std::vector`. Python `list` seems to be implemented as an array, and has no `push_front` equivalents.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I agree, I probably was thinking more beyond the simplistic approach.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in C are just pointers and they don't contains an information about their length. So, C-programmer should keep not only a pointer but it's length too. Here's a snippet to erase a particular value from "C-array"

```
/// \return a new length
int removeFromArray( int * array, int arrayLength, int elementToRemove ) {
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++ ) {
        if ( array[ i ] == elementToRemove ) {
            memmove( & array[ i ], & array[ i + 1 ], arrayLength - i - 1 );
            return arrayLength - 1;
        }
    }
    return arrayLength;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ either you can use `std::list` or `std::vector` based on your mileage

If you need to implement in `C`, you need to write your double-link list implementation or if you wan't to emulate `std::vector`, you can do so by using `memcpy` and `array indexing`

Comment: Or `std::array` or `std::deque`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I believe the closest stl data-structure to Python List would be std::deque

Comment: I am not completely sure, I haven't used python for a while. But there is a `collections.deque` data structure, which makes me wonder...

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914233/what-is-the-underlying-data-structure-for-python-lists) seems to suggest that the underlying structure is an array.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you don't want or able to use standard library (BTW, why?).

You can look into the code of the vector template in one of STL implementations and see, how it's implemented.

The basic algorithm is simple. If you're deleting something from the middle of the array, you must shrink it after. If you're inserting into the middle - you must expand it before. Sometimes it involves memory reallocation and moving you array, by `memcpy` for example.

Or you can implement double-linked list as mentioned. But it won't behave like array.

Comment: No, I want to use standart library. But I'm very intrested in the algorithm that I can implement.