# What is the underlying data structure for python tuples?

Tags: python, python-internals

What's the underlying data structure for the built-in tuple data type?

The following links to a similar question:
[What is the underlying data structure for Python lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914233/what-is-the-underlying-data-structure-for-python-lists)